# Excel Calculate First and Last entry of time for each day of each employee

Tags: excel

I am trying to calculate total number of hours each employ worked per day in excel for example on day  `1/10/2015 11:45` employ card no `12345` if has 5 entries i want to select only select   `1/10/2015 11:45` first and last entry of that particular  employ last entry `1/10/2015 11:49` and calculate total hours worked for that day and show that employees card number unique date and time worked as there are many employee am not sure how to achieve this i need a formula that can help me .

```
Date and Time   Card Number
1/10/2015 11:45     12345
1/10/2015 11:46     12345
1/10/2015 11:47     12345
1/10/2015 11:48     12345
1/10/2015 11:49     12345
1/10/2015 11:45     1236
1/10/2015 11:46     1236
1/10/2015 11:47     1236
1/10/2015 11:48     1236
1/10/2015 11:49     1236
1/11/2015 11:49     12345
1/11/2015 11:50     12345
1/11/2015 11:51     12345
1/11/2015 11:52     12345
1/11/2015 11:53     12345
1/11/2015 11:49     1236
1/11/2015 11:50     1236
1/11/2015 11:51     1236
1/11/2015 11:52     1236
1/11/2015 11:53     1236
1/12/2015 11:54     123
1/12/2015 11:55     123
1/12/2015 11:55     123
1/12/2015 11:55     123
1/12/2015 11:56     123
1/12/2015 11:57     123
1/12/2015 11:54     12345
1/12/2015 11:55     12345
1/12/2015 11:55     12345
1/12/2015 11:55     12345
1/12/2015 11:56     12345
1/12/2015 11:57     12345
```

Expected output

[I have uploaded an excel that can help](http://filebin.ca/2QhDXhFVyOc4/Myerror1.xlsx)

Comment: You could sort it on Card Number, and then have a column with an if statement saying something like, if same as above copy value and clear the cell above. You only would need a special case for the first row then.

Comment: @Luuklag thanks for the reply can u help me formula or the example that would be more help full for me

Comment: I deleted my answer, because your workbook made me realise that the problem is bigger then I actually thought. I think it is best if you go for a VBA solution here, as that would work way more efficient. You could have a look at the tag `[excel-vba]`

Comment: Is there at least one time stamp for each minute, as you show above.  If so, you might be able to `Remove Duplicates` and then use a Pivot Table, with the Count function and grouping by days, to get the number of minutes worked.  If not, a VBA solution will be required.  By the way, this is not a free code-writing service, so take these ideas, come up with something, and post your efforts with problem statements here so we can help you.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld there is no time stamp for every minut i have used if for demo the entry happens only when a swipe happens that is 4-5 times a day i tried with `Pivot Table` that is very difficult

Comment: Then you will need a VBA solution.  Or a lot of manual formula entries to replicate the output you show on your worksheet.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your spreadsheet this will return the figures:
in cell F9 enter
`=MIN(IF($B$2:$B$33=$E9,IF(INT($A$2:$A$33)=F$7,$A$2:$A$33)))` as an array formula, and in G9 enter 
`=MAX(IF($B$2:$B$33=$E9,IF(INT($A$2:$A$33)=F$7,$A$2:$A$33)))` also as an array formula.

Edit:  Erray formula - enter using Ctrl+Shift+Enter and you'll get { } around your formula.